# Bootstrap flex nested row positioning side by side instead one under another

Tags: nested, grid, rows, positioning

Im trying to do trivial bootstrap nested rows positioning and I cannot understand why my rows position side by side instead typical and desired behavior of laying down one under another. I tried to replicate it on fiddlejs and it works as expected, but on my real project somehow behave strange (for me) Please refer to the screenshot. Green and red boxes shows rows which are nested under one column. Each of the rows has column with content within. Probably reason is trivial but i cannot figure it out. Thanks [my page with problematic nested rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj3cY.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I found what cause the problem. .input-group class doesn't work well with .col class, causing nested row not being stacked one under another. Deleting .input-group did the job.
[Page with proper rows stack alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgHdS.png)